# How does one delete a directory filled with files and other subdirectory permanently, bypassing the trash, from the command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

So my command line skills are a little rusty and I'm having trouble remembering the differences between the meanings of flags in different distro's os's.  I also don't really remember all my technical lingo so manpages seem really unclear.

Basically I'm on Mac OS X and want to delete a directory along with all of its contents.  What I'm mainly concerned about, I suppose, is that it'll delete literally ALL of the references within the directory, including ../ and ../`<everything else, including ../'s own ../>` and then just totally screw up my entire system.

Which of these do I want to run?

```
$ rm -R dir-name/
```

or

```
$ rm -r
```

Comment: Jon, please click the checkmark next to one of the responses if they answer your question. This will mark your problem solved and reward the person answering.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to delete `foo/bar`, the command you want is `rm -r foo/bar` (assuming you are working in the directory that contains `foo`). This will delete `bar` and everything in it, but leave `foo` and anything else in it alone.

`rm -r` is clever enough not to recurse into `../` - otherwise every `rm -r` would delete everything.

Answer (score 4):

If you run:

```
rm -r
```

without passing it a directory/file argument, nothing will happen.

There is no difference between:

```
rm -r xyz
rm -R xyz
rm -r xyz/
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add -f if you don't want prompting for confirmation:

```
rm -rf xyz
```